# 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using the PIL library.

I am trying to make an image look red-er, this is what i've got.

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('balloon.jpg')
pixels = list(image.getdata())
for pixel in pixels: 
    pixel[0] = pixel[0] + 20    
image.putdata(pixels)
image.save('new.bmp')
```

However I get this error: `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: I'm sure PIL can simply put a red layer over your image. If you have any red pixels in your image this approach will fail!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

PIL pixels are tuples, and tuples are immutable. You need to construct a new tuple. So, instead of the for loop, do:

```
pixels = [(pixel[0] + 20, pixel[1], pixel[2]) for pixel in pixels]
image.putdata(pixels)
```

Also, if the pixel is already too red, adding 20 will overflow the value. You probably want something like `min(pixel[0] + 20, 255)` or `int(255 * (pixel[0] / 255.) ** 0.9)` instead of `pixel[0] + 20`.

And, to be able to handle images in lots of different formats, do `image = image.convert("RGB")` after opening the image. The [convert](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm#Image.convert) method will ensure that the pixels are always (r, g, b) tuples.

Comment: i think your solution is more akin to my problem. However, even if i do: pixel = (0,0,0). I get the exact same picture as the imported one.

Comment: You probably meant min(pixel[0] + 20, 255)

Answer (score 9):

The second line should have been `pixels[0]`, with an S. You probably have a tuple named `pixel`, and tuples are immutable. Construct new pixels instead:

```
image = Image.open('balloon.jpg')

pixels = [(pix[0] + 20,) + pix[1:] for pix in image.getdata()]

image.putdate(pixels)
```

Answer (score 6):

Tuples, in python can't have their values changed. If you'd like to change the contained values though I suggest using a list:

`[1,2,3]` not `(1,2,3)`

Answer (score 3):

A tuple is immutable and thus you get the error you posted.

```
>>> pixels = [1, 2, 3]
>>> pixels[0] = 5
>>> pixels = (1, 2, 3)
>>> pixels[0] = 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

In your specific case, as correctly pointed out in other answers, you should write:

```
pixel = (pixel[0] + 20, pixel[1], pixel[2])
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want the next transformation for you pixels:

```
pixels = map(list, image.getdata())
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelt the second `pixels` as `pixel`. The following works:

```
pixels = [1,2,3]
pixels[0] = 5
```

It appears that due to the typo you were trying to accidentally modify some tuple called `pixel`, and in Python tuples are immutable. Hence the confusing error message.