# Changing a value in a dictionary from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Currently I'm testing something in python and trying to figure out if I can change a value in another file. Currently I have this written down :

```py
from items import items

def changingitemamount(name, value):
    print(items[name][6])
    items[name][6] = items[name][6] + int(value)
    print(items[name][6])

def changingitemamounttext():
    name = input("What do you want to change?")
    value = input("How much do you want to add?")
    changingitemamount(name,value)
```

But whenever I run it and go to add the value i get this error.

```
items[name][6] = items[name][6] + int(value)

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: What's `items` in this import?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['tuple' object does not support item assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687510/tuple-object-does-not-support-item-assignment)

Comment: what does your `print(items[name][6])` print out?

Comment: `items[name]` is clearly a tuple, use a list instead

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11458239/python-changing-value-in-a-tuple to see how to change value in a tuple

Comment: `items[name][6]  += int(value)` is equivalent of `items[name][6] = items[name][6] + int(value)`

Comment: `items[name][6]` is a tuple (immutable data-type) so  that is why you get `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: @Sayse Even after changing it to a tuple I still get an error. This time around its "print(items(name)[6])
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable"

Comment: @Sayse Dah sorry. Messed up and typed tuple instead of list. Still. I swapped everything to parethesis since i made this mistake before. And my lists are well. Already lists.

Answer (score 0):

A tuple is immutable please convert them into a list and do your operations and then you can revert them back to tuples.

Like :

```
x = (4,5)       
listNumbers = list(x)  
print(listNumbers)
y = tuple(listNumbers)
print(x)
```

Hope this helps.